# How do I show the drop-down in a combobox in WPF?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

When the user starts typing in a combobox, auto-complete kicks in and shows the closest match.  What I want to do is have the drop-down become visible as well, as if the user clicked the down arrow.  Can this be done and if yes, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could hook the `KeyDown` event on the `ComboBox`, and then set the `IsDropDownOpen` property to true.

in XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="MyComboBox"
          IsEditable="True"
          IsReadOnly="False"
          KeyDown="MyComboBox_KeyDown"/>
```

in code behind:

```
private void MyComboBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
    if (MyComboBox.Text.Length > 0)
        MyComboBox.IsDropDownOpen = true;
}
```

Comment: PreviewKeyDown would be a better place.  Opening the drop down resets the text position in the textbox.

Comment: Thanks!  This worked.  I was hoping there was some cool way to do it in the XAML, but this works.

Answer (score 0):

```
ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox;
comboBox.DroppedDown = true;
```