# Combobox TouchDown and MouseDown does not fire

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using WPF and has a combobox which is editable.

I added TouchDown and MouseDown event handler, but it never fire up when I touch on the combobox.

What I plan to do is to have the drop down listed down when I touch or click on the combobox.

How can I do it?

```xml
<ComboBox Name="cbProductList" Height="45" Width="260" IsEditable="True"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ProductsSource}}" 
        DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="ProductId"
        SelectedIndex="0" FontSize="23" FontFamily="Segoe WP"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
        SelectionChanged="cbProductList_SelectionChanged" />
```

---

Found this:
[How do I show the drop-down in a combobox in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547767/how-do-i-show-the-drop-down-in-a-combobox-in-wpf)

But this event fire when something is type. I want it to fire when the combobox is clicked.

Comment: Can you provide the combobox XAML and the event handler signatures

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the property `AutoPostBack="true"`:

```xml
<ComboBox Name="cbProductList" Height="45" Width="260" IsEditable="True"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ProductsSource}}" 
        DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="ProductId"
        SelectedIndex="0" FontSize="23" FontFamily="Segoe WP"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
        SelectionChanged="cbProductList_SelectionChanged"
        autopostback="true" />
```